# Kotlin - any substitute for companion object inside of another object (not class)?

Tags: android, design-patterns, kotlin

I would like in my Kotlin Android app to have singleton object with some static definitions of it's inner states.

As I understand, `object` in Kotlin is for singleton, so I am trying this kind of approach:

```
object MySingleton
{
    public const val _DEF_DEFINITION_NO_ONE: Byte = 1;
    public const val _DEF_DEFINITION_NO_TWO: Byte = 2;
    (...)
}
```

This is fine, but the problem is, to being able use these definitions, now I must create Object's instance first.

Just wondering if I am able in Kotlin to create this kind of construction and have access to these definitions without creating `MySingleton` instance? Answer would be `companion object` working similar as `static` in other languages, but it's not allowed inside objects, only inside of classes.

Of course I can leave this as is or make these definitions global, but would like to know is it possible to do in a way I described? Or maybe should I design this in another yet way?

Comment: `now I must create Object's instance first`
Did it work ?

Comment: @voddan I thought so, because I used this inside of main activity: `private var myPrivateVar: MySingleton = MySingleton`, and it did not caused syntax error. Seems like it's only copying reference in this case, or something like this. Sorry, I am still new in Kotlin.

Comment: I see. Since any instance initialization is an action, it is always requires braces like a function call `MyClass()`. That's how you know you call a constructor and create an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, `MySingleton` is an `object` and thus a **singleton**. There's no need to create an instance of it (not even possible). You simply access it's constants in a static way like this: `MySingleton._DEF_DEFINITION_NO_ONE`.

If you want to use the constants without prefixing the `object` name, just import them with the fully-qualified name and use it as follows:

```
import package.MySingleton._DEF_DEFINITION_NO_ONE
//...
println(_DEF_DEFINITION_NO_ONE)
```

Comment: Can I use constants without initializing the object itself? Assume, that my `object` is pretty heavy to initialize, thus I'm doing it lazily, when needed. But I want to access static fields. Can that be achieved?

Comment: If declared as `object` the compiler will take care of creating it. There's only one single instance at runtime. You can't access these constants before the object is created because an object always gets created

Comment: @garbus If you plan to do heavy lifting inside your object's init block, don't do it. In general one should not do that during class instantiation / object creation. But the fields should be accessible as shown by Simon and me anyways.

Comment: Ah, so compiler creates this instance for me automatically. Did not know that. Thanks for clearing out.

Comment: It's happening in the generated bytecode (to be exact)

Comment: By the way, the object is created lazily on the first access, just like you wanted

Comment: Okay, the info about auto-creating this object helped definitely. I misunderstood the idea of objects in Kotlin. Thanks!

Comment: @WilliMentzel, no, I just want to keep there state of the app and name these states with human readable properties, so they will be grouped inside of this object and accessible from outside as well. This in fact works as you described, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways to work with static data in Kotlin:

**An `object`**

```
object ASingleton {
    val CONSTANT_PROPERTY: Int = 1;
}
```

If you need a single instance class, which has only one state for each property, use a singleton. Note: There can only be one instance of this class and it is created for you by the compiler.

**A class with a `companion object`**

```
class ClassWithCompanionObject{

    val someProperty: Int = 0; // instance bound

    companion object {
        val CONSTANT_PROPERTY: Int = 1;
    }
}
```

If you need some static properties, and the rest should have a state which is bound to a certain instance, go with the class with `companion object`.

Usage:

```
println(ASingleton.CONSTANT_PROPERTY)
println(ClassWithCompanionObject.CONSTANT_PROPERTY)
```